# Eclipse Stops Abruptly

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running:
Eclipse 3.7.2(BIRT with Java 1.5)
JDK 1.5.22 (I have an app which runs only on Java 1.5)
Linux Mint 17
When I'm running Eclipse, it stops abruptly. 
Here are my eclipse.ini file contents:

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vm
    /usr/programs/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java
    -vmargs
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
```

I've tried many things as suggested in this site. I've also re-installed Eclipse. Still the same problem. Please Help....
Here's the .log file:

```
    !SESSION 2014-07-02 12:05:50.774 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
    java.version=1.5.0_22
    java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
    BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
    Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-07-02 12:05:59.863
    !MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator 
    operation
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-07-02 12:05:59.863
    !MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+D R:
    Binding(ALT+SHIFT+D R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.rap.ui.launch.RAPLaunchShortcut.debug,Debug RAP 
    Application,
    Debug RAP Application,
    Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
    ,
    ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Comment: Did you try to increase XXMaxPermSize parameter to 512m or greater?

Comment: The log file at `workspace/.metadata/.log` might provide the answer.

Comment: Note: the Runtime used to execute Eclipse does not have to be the same Runtime to run the application you're developing. You can configure a different runtime for your workspace.

Comment: Yes I've tried with XXMaxPermSize=512. But the same problem

Comment: Eclipse versions starting with Kepler are Java 6 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I re-installed everything and tried. Got the the same issue.
So I have switched backed to Linux Mint 13. Everything works fine now.
Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On newer Linux Distros I have had issues with older versions of Eclipse.
Eclipse 3.7 was originally released around 2011 I think.
Eclipse uses a lot of C/C++ in the back.

Try run the sample Eclipse on a much older Mint / Ubuntu. I am betting the issue will go away.
Perhaps test it in a VM from http://virtualboximages.com/
Ubuntu 12.04 would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Yes I've run the same setup in Linux-Mint 13 without any issues, the past year.

Comment: I am guessing you updated your packages or installed a new package on your Mint that pushed in a new glibc for instance.
I may be wrong, but your symptoms sound identical to a problem I faced in the past.

Comment: Yes. I had accidentally updated some Level 5 upgrades with the Update Manager.